# Discord.js slash commands with embeds

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to build an embed with slash commands. This is an error I am getting and for the life of me I cannot figure out what is wrong. I know this embed itself works as I had it in the old bot and it ran fine, however as soon as I update the command handler it has stopped working. It seems that it is unable to find the embeds description yet I have one set so I am really unsure why it is not reading it

```
node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
data.embeds[0].description: This field is required
    at RequestHandler.execute (node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/interactions/987187176422907954/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246OTg3MTg3MTc2NDIyOTA3OTU0OnBuWmNoTmVoOXltU0pydG9WOXpJenUzeTRPSDBybllDZEZSME9RandlOExpYlFFckRteG1sa1RVV2NycmhQbmpsenpRb1ZBdzhLQ3hGV09WR0dKcHI2QlQ2bjZMWFZWVVU3Q3pzN0tVT24xV1F6S1psVG41UGhWVHZYUzl4alZ4/callback',
  code: 50035,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      type: 4,
      data: {
        content: undefined,
        tts: false,
        nonce: undefined,
        embed: {
          title: null,
          type: 'rich',
          description: null,
          url: null,
          timestamp: null,
          color: null,
          fields: [],
          thumbnail: null,
          image: null,
          author: null,
          footer: null
        },
        embeds: [
          {
            title: null,
            type: 'rich',
            description: null,
            url: null,
            timestamp: null,
            color: null,
            fields: [],
            thumbnail: null,
            image: null,
            author: null,
            footer: null
          }
        ],
        username: undefined,
        avatar_url: undefined,
        allowed_mentions: undefined,
        flags: undefined,
        files: []
      }
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

And this is the code in question

```js
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const config = require("../settings/config")

module.exports = {
    slash: true,
    testOnly: true,
    description: "Gives latency of the bot",
    /**
     * 
     * @param {CommandInteration} interaction 
     * @param {Client} client
     */
    callback: async (interaction, client) => {
        const Build = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(config.settings.EmbedColour)
        .setTitle('**Ping / API Latency:**')
        .setDescription(` ${Date.now() - interaction.createdTimestamp}ms.`)
        .setFooter({ text: `${interaction.guild.name} | Made By WildFyr#0008`, iconURL: interaction.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }) })

        return ({embeds: [Build]})
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error and how to fix it?
Here is the Config.js, I removed all tokens and IDs and what not

```js
const config =  {
    settings: {
        Token: 'BOT TOKEN', //Visit https://discord.com/developers/applications and get your bots token
        LicenseKey: 'LICENSE KEY', //Visist https://license.wildfyr.net to get your keys
        BotApplicationID: 'BOT USER ID', //Bot's user ID
        BotOwnerID: 'USER ID', //Your user ID, used for Owner only commands
        GuildID: 'GUILD ID', //The ID for your Server
        EmbedColour: '#fc6a03', //The colour you want the side bar of the embeds to be
        botActivity: {
            status: 'online', //Online, idle, dnd, offline
            activity: {
                name: 'Whatever you want', //The name of the game the bot is playing
                type: 'PLAYING', //Playing, Watching, Streaming, Listening
            }
        },
        deleteCommands: 'TRUE', //Deletes the command after a set ammount of time, reduces chat spam
        ShowTriggeredEvents: 'FALSE', //Used for De-Bugging, prints in console everytime someone runs a command
    }
}

module.exports = config;
```

@新Acesyyy
This is what I get after changing that.

```
commands\ping.js:15
        .setColor(config.settings[0].EmbedColour)
                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'EmbedColour')
    at Command.callback [as _callback] (commands\ping.js:15:38)
    at SlashCommands.<anonymous> (node_modules\wokcommands\dist\SlashCommands.js:177:54)
    at step (node_modules\wokcommands\dist\SlashCommands.js:44:23)
    at Object.next (node_modules\wokcommands\dist\SlashCommands.js:25:53)
    at node_modules\wokcommands\dist\SlashCommands.js:19:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (node_modules\wokcommands\dist\SlashCommands.js:15:12)
    at SlashCommands.invokeCommand (node_modules\wokcommands\dist\SlashCommands.js:168:16)
    at SlashCommands.<anonymous> (node_modules\wokcommands\dist\SlashCommands.js:67:26)
    at step (node_modules\wokcommands\dist\SlashCommands.js:44:23)
    at Object.next (node_modules\wokcommands\dist\SlashCommands.js:25:53)
    at node_modules\wokcommands\dist\SlashCommands.js:19:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (node_modules\wokcommands\dist\SlashCommands.js:15:12)
    at WebSocketManager.<anonymous> (node_modules\wokcommands\dist\SlashCommands.js:58:86)
    at WebSocketManager.emit (node:events:390:28)
```

Comment: Can you also share your  `const config = require("../settings/config")` file?

Comment: Yep, just edited it to include it

Comment: Can you try with this? `config.settings[0].EmbedColour`

Comment: Added the error above after editing that

Comment: Can you screen shot your folders? your code works to me. Maybe you got a wrong call with your file

Comment: `config.settings` is an object so using `config.settings[0]` wouldn't get anything as it expects an array unless there was a property in the object with the key of `0`, which is why it is coming as undefined

Comment: @新Acesyyy
https://media.wildfyr.net/WildFyr/DPzP0H.png
https://media.wildfyr.net/WildFyr/-xrVe6.png
https://media.wildfyr.net/WildFyr/csR3l6.png
https://media.wildfyr.net/WildFyr/FWEpHy.png

Answer (score 1):

Your error message is showing that you're trying to access `config.settings[0].EmbedColour` which will return the first index object in the array.

However, it appears that `config.settings` is the only item in the `config` object.

`config.settings.EmbedColour` is the property you want to access.

Answer (score 1):

DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body

The error is indicating that the embeds[0].description field is required, but it's not provided in your code. Looking at your callback function, you are creating a MessageEmbed but not setting the description field. You need to set the description field for the embed:

```
const Build = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(config.settings.EmbedColour)
    .setTitle('**Ping / API Latency:**')
    .setDescription(` ${Date.now() - interaction.createdTimestamp}ms.`)
    .setFooter(`${interaction.guild.name} | Made By WildFyr#0008`, interaction.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }));
```

Make sure to set the description field in the MessageEmbed instance.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'EmbedColour')

The error indicates that config.settings is undefined or not an object. This is likely due to a misconfiguration in your config.js. Make sure that config.settings is defined and is an object. You might want to change your config.js to the following:

```
const config =  {
    settings: {
        Token: 'BOT TOKEN',
        LicenseKey: 'LICENSE KEY',
        BotApplicationID: 'BOT USER ID',
        BotOwnerID: 'USER ID',
        GuildID: 'GUILD ID',
        EmbedColour: '#fc6a03',
        botActivity: {
            // ... rest of the properties
        },
        deleteCommands: 'TRUE',
        ShowTriggeredEvents: 'FALSE',
    }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Ensure that config.settings.EmbedColour is defined in your configuration.

Make these changes and see if it resolves your issues. If you still encounter problems, double-check your configuration and make sure all required fields are properly set.

Comment: I recommend you use a bit of markdown to separate the issues. `---` creates a horizontal line

Answer (score -1):

Maybe Instead of returning the embed, try replying to the interaction

```
interaction.reply({embeds: [Build]})
```

Comment: I had that before, and it was telling me that reply was not a function... I didn't figure out how to define reply because I know it is a function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @WildFyr, your callback function parameters need curly braces around them to access the interaction and client. Try that and tell me if it works